# How do I get the POST data from a nuxtjs server middleware?

Tags: express, nuxt.js

How do I get the POST data from a nuxtjs server middleware? So far I've managed to do it for GET, but for POST the body is just not there. `req.body` is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to `nuxt.config.js`:

```
serverMiddleware: [
  '~/api/v1/index.js'
],
```

and then create a file `/api/v1/index.js` with:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = require('express')()
module.exports = { path: '/api', handler: app }
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/newsletter/subscribe', (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body)
})
```

Key line is `app.use(bodyParser.json())`
Even if you are not using express, the code is still very similar.

Comment: Very useful! Thanks! I don't know why this is not in the docs. I added it and referenced this question (https://github.com/nuxt/nuxtjs.org/pull/711)

Comment: Someone should try using `express.Router()` instead of what I've done `require('express')()` - post another answer if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use express because nuxt server already running connect instance for this. Just do this for receiving the POST request:

yourservermiddleware.js -

```
export default {
    path: '/yourservermiddlware',
    async handler(req, res, next) {

        req.on('data', async (data) => {
            let payload = JSON.parse(data.toString())
            console.log("received request", payload)
            res.end(JSON.stringify('send back what you want'))
            next()
        })


        
    }
}
```

P.S. and do not forget to register servermiddleware at the nuxt.config.js