# How do I get the POST data from a nuxtjs server middleware without using express packge

Tags: express, nuxt.js, body-parser

how can I pass data and get it in ServerMiddleware when I call the POST method without using the express package?

I have tried to apply this solution but it's not working without using express :
[How do I get the POST data from a nuxtjs server middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202526/how-do-i-get-the-post-data-from-a-nuxtjs-server-middleware)

Comment: What is the issue with this package? Are you okay with another one like h3?

Comment: I am trying to use  [body-parser] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) without using the express.js package. and inject body-parser to nuxt.js middleware so i can get the body when i am using POST method

Comment: What is the issue with express? You need it for `body-parser` as seen in the above documentation.

Comment: we do not want to use express, since nuxt has server Middleware built-in. trying to find a minimalist approach and light way of practice. since the source code is a huge large-scaling app

Comment: As mentioned above, give a try to h3 so: https://github.com/unjs/h3